# copy spreadsheet and add trigger to new one

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I have a large number of simple spreadsheets (each shared with a different agent), and one large "management" spreadsheet that is used to interface with all of them.

When adding a new agent, I use a script (bound to the management-spreadsheet), to copy and rename a template-spreadsheet. The template-spreadsheet has an onEdit trigger which is *not* copied to the new instance. When I try to add it after copying (see script below), it is added to the management-spreadsheet instead of the new spreadsheet.

```
function NewAgent(filename) {
  // create new spreadsheet from template
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(AgentFolder).next();
  var tmplt = DriveApp.getFilesByName(AgentTemplate);
  var newfile = tmplt.next().makeCopy(filename, folder );
  var newspread = SpreadsheetApp.openById( newfile.getId() );

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("MyFunction").forSpreadsheet(newspread).onEdit().create();

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

The function `MyFunction` is bound to the template (and also appears in the script bound to the new spreadsheet).
The function `NewAgent` is, as stated bound to the management script.
The result is that the trigger is added to the management-spreadsheet...

ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The issue might be your were referring to the "newfile" variable.

```
    function NewAgent(filename) {
      // create new spreadsheet from template
      var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(AgentFolder).next();
      var tmplt = DriveApp.getFilesByName(AgentTemplate);
      var newfile = tmplt.next().makeCopy(filename, folder );
      var newspread = SpreadsheetApp.openById( DriveApp.getFilesByName(        filename ) );
    }
```

ScriptApp.newTrigger("MyFunction").forSpreadsheet(newspread).onEdit().create();

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [forSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forSpreadsheet(String)) accepts a Spreadsheet ID as an argument, and your sending the file, remove `SpreadsheetApp.openById(` from the code and it should be fine:

```
var newspread = newfile.getId();
```

Comment: Hi Kriggs, and thanks. apparently `forSpreadsheet()` has two methods, one which accepts a string (ID) and the other which takes the spreadsheet object itself - see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forSpreadsheet(Spreadsheet)).
Sadly, both led to the same result I described above.